# One-Sided Alternative Hypothesis in a Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel (CMH) Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, inference, chi-squared-test, cochran-mantel-haenszel

"A novel treatment is being developed and to measure its efficacy, the proportion $P_1$ of treated subjects who benefit from a certain Positive Outcome will be compared against the proportion $P_2$ of untreated subjects who do.
The statistical hypothesis is:
$$\begin{align}
H_0: P_1 = P_2 \newline
H_a: P_1 > P_2
\end{align}$$
As other covariates will be used to stratify the populations, the CMH test will be used to test the difference between the two proportions **at a one-sided significance level of $\alpha$**. The p-value from the Chi-squared test will be used to confirm whether these proportions are equal: if $p < \alpha$ then the null hypothesis will be rejected."

The source of my confusion stems from the one-sidedness of the hypothesis and the rejecting of $H_0$ if $p < \alpha$ (my intuition tells me I should reject if $p < 2\alpha$), considering the fact that the distribution of the test statistic under $H_0$ is a $\chi^2$, rather than a distribution with two tails. Everywhere I look, the standard alternative hypothesis for this test for the $2\times2\times K$ case is that $P_1 \neq P_2$. If one were to observe that $P_1 > P_2$ in our sample, would it be acceptable to consider the $2\alpha$ tail of the $\chi^2$ distribution, being that the tail of the $\chi^2$ distribution with one degree of freedom "contains" both $\alpha$ tails of the standard normal? Is $P_1$ being greater than $P_2$ in our sample evidence that our CMH statistic was the result of squaring the positive realization of a standard normal random variable?